# LINQ to SQL oddity

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, sqlite

I have a database table with a field that has values such as

```
AAAA
BBBB0001
BBBB0002
CCCC
CCCC
CCCC
```

and I would like to know how many AAAAs, BBBBs and CCCCs there are (1, 2 and 3 here).

If I set up a couple of test queries in LinqPad with those values in an array:

```
var Table = new [] {"AAAA", "BBBB1", "BBBB2", "CCCC", "CCCC", "CCCC"};

var query1 = Table.GroupBy(d => d).Select( g => new { K = g.Key, C = g.Count()});
query1.Dump();

var query2 = Table.GroupBy(d => d.Substring(0, 4)).Select( g => new { K = g.Key, C = g.Count()});
query2.Dump();
```

then I get the results I expect - in the first case grouped by the key and in the second grouped by the first four characters of the key

```
AAAA    1
BBBB1   1
BBBB2   1
CCCC    3

AAAA    1
BBBB    2
CCCC    3
```

which is fine. But if replace the array by a SQLite table and run the same queries, what I get is

```
AAAA    1
BBBB1   1
BBBB2   1
CCCC    3

AAAA    1
BBBB    1
BBBB    1
CCCC    3
```

That is, the first is correct, while in the second, the field is being correctly shortened but the grouping is wrong.

Anyone cast any light on this?

Andrew

Comment: SQLite isn't LINQ to SQL, is it? It sounds like a but in the LINQ to SQLite provider. I suggest you look at the generated SQL...

Comment: Most likely the SQL being generated isn't correct for SQLite. Probably the grouping is being done before the key truncation. Can you post what's being generated?

Comment: Thanks both - it does turn out to be a bug - adding an AsEnumerable() and forcing the group to be done locally is a fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What connector are you using for your linq to sqlite? It feels like it's likely to be a bug in that connector.

e.g. Looking at the revision table for dotconnect - http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/revision_history.html - then there are plenty of group by bugs that they've found and fixed in recent months - and I'm sure there could be others in there.

---

Unless you absolutely need sqlite, then you could consider switching to SQL CE - in which case you'd get more direct support for Linq from Microsoft.

Comment: Thanks Stuart - I'm forced to use Sqlite in this instance.